# Form behaving differently on small screens vs desktop screen

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7, google-maps, autocomplete

I have an issue and I would be grateful for any ideas!

I'm using a simple template bought at ThemeForest and I successfully added google maps autocomplete functionality for addresses in a field via a script on the contact 7 form (so far so good).

However, when I make the window narrow (or I look at the website on the cellphone) the autocomplete script doesn't work. What could cause this??

big screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRUYo.jpg

small screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/peB13.png

Comment: Have you looked at the code using Inspector/Developer? It would be useful to know if the address is being output in the code (whilst in mobile view) or not, as that might indicate CSS rather than something else. I don't think I can answer your question but a bit more detail might help you get a reply from others.

Comment: I thought it looked the same but upon closer inspection I notice that the specific field is missing 'autocomplete="off" ' when on mobile view.  (I have another similar form on the site which works fine and it has the ' autocomplete="off" ' on mobile as well.  This might be it?  but I don't understand why is being removed

Comment: Its maybe worth trying to edit the HTML directly in Inspector to add back in that attribute to see if it then works but as to the why it's not outputting that I couldn't say. If the script you are using is something thats directly supported by CF7 then perhaps try raising a question via their Support page on Wordpress? That plugin is well looked after so you have a good chance of getting a reply.

Comment: I added it manually but it made no change.  And is just a javascript that I added to the form.  Thank you for your help

Comment: ... or if the script you are using is Javascript(?) perhaps post a question on StackOverflow and include the full script code?

Comment: Maybe instead of creating custom scripts use a plugin to do this?  [Smart grid-layout extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/) allows you to build resposnive forms, while [Google Maps for CF7 forms](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-google-map/) allows you to add maps with search/autocomplete functionality.  The 2 plugins are compatible.